# Align 2 images right in linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to align 2 images in right side in linear layout.How to add space between 2 images? 
Here is my code.

Vechile.xml

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   <Image
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" />

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />                

  <Image
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img2"
    android:id="@+id/image2"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your LinearLayout gravity right and take some margin in your ImageViews like this:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow_down_black_24dp"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow_down_black_24dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```